# How to handle my data?

Tags: php, html, concatenation

**Edit: The aim of my method is to delete a value from a string in a database.**

I cant seem to find the answer for this one anywhere. Can you concatenate inside a str_replace like this:

```
str_replace($pid . ",","",$boom);
```

- $pid is a page id, eg 40
- $boom is an exploded array

If i have a string: 40,56,12 i want to make it 56,12 however without the concatenator in it will produce:

> ,56,12

When I have the concat in the str_replace it doesnt do a thing. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please explain the contents of `$boom` a bit more?

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate strings in the way you did. The problem is probably elsewhere. What variable is getting the result of your str_replace?

Comment: $boom is the result from a string in the database with a comma as a delimiter which gets exploded into an array (with comma as delimit). I will post the relevant code of that file in my original post now.

Comment: @IanGarratt: Then you destroy your data and `str_replace` is not the right tool for the job. Probably `implode`/`explode` isn't as well and you should not wonder that it does not work.

Comment: @IanGarratt: I updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9650886/367456), you find some example at the top which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @hakre thanks for the comment! I have looked at it and I will look into array_search, at the moment one answer works however i think i have spotted a flaw in it, so if i have i will take a more in depth look at yours! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have edited it becomes clear that you want to remove the value of `$pid` from the array `$boom` which contains one number as a value. You can use `array_search` to find if it is in at if in with which key. You can then `unset` the element from `$boom`:

```
$pid = '40';
$boom = explode(',', '40,56,12');
$r = array_search($pid, $boom, FALSE);
if ($r !== FALSE) {
    unset($boom[$r]);
}
```

---

Old question:

> Can you concatenate inside a str_replace like this: ... ?

Yes you can, see the example:

```
$pid = '40';
$boom = array('40,56,12');
print_r(str_replace($pid . ",", "", $boom));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 56,12
)
```

Which is pretty much like you did so you might be looking for the problem at the wrong place. You can use any string *expression* for the parameter.

It might be easier for you if you're unsure to create a variable first:

```
$pid = '40';
$boom = array('40,56,12');
$search = sprintf("%d,", $pid);
print_r(str_replace($search, "", $boom));
```

Comment: OP: "$boom is an exploded array". Perhaps `$boom = array(40, 56, 12);` then?

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question: yes you can. That code works as you would expect it to.

But this approach is wrong. It will not work for `$pid = 12;` (last element, without trailing coma) and will incorrectly replace `40,` in `$boom = '140,20,12'`;

You should keep it in array, search for unwanted value, if found unset it from the array and then implode  with coma.

```
$boom = array_filter($boom);
$key = array_search($pid, $boom);
if($key !== false){
    unset($boom[$key]);
}
$boom = implode(',',$boom);
```

[+] Your code does not work because `$boom` is an array, and `str_replace` operates on string.

Answer (score 2):

As $boom is an array, you don't need to use array on your case.

Change this

```
$boom = explode(",",$ticket_array);
$boom = str_replace($pid . ",","",$boom);
$together = implode(",",$boom);
```

to

```
$together = str_replace($pid . ",","",$ticket_array);
```

---

#### Update: If you want still want to use array

```
$boom = explode(",",$ticket_array);
unset($boom[array_search($pid, $boom)]);
$together = implode(",",$boom);
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I guess i didnt need to use an array I had no need to! Thanks!

Comment: @Starx: [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace) works well on arrays (of strings). Your string method however will have flaws in replacing every number which has a 40 before the comma, like `140,240` etc. - and it won't work if 40 is the last number `36,38,40`.

Comment: Although it works for this case, this approach is still error-prone. In my answer I had explained why.

Comment: @hakre, You misunderstood my point. SO I updated it. And an array solution also, which works perfectly

Comment: @Starx: Check the return value of `array_search` first. FALSE will result in 0 and unset an element that is not what you have looked for. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

You could use str_split, it converts a string to an array, then with a foreach loop echo all the values except the first one.

```
$numbers_string="40,56,12";
$numbers_array = str_split($numbers_string);
//then, when you have the array of numbers, you could echo every number except the first separating them with a comma
foreach ($numbers_array as $key => $value) {
  if ($key > 0) {
    echo $value . ", ";
  }
}
```

If you want is to skip a value not by it's position in the array, but for it's value then you could do this instead:

```
$unwanted_value="40";
foreach ($numbers_array as $key => $value) {
  if ($value != $unwanted_value) {

    echo $value . ", ";
  }
  else {
    unset($numbers_array[$key]);
    $numbers_array = array_values($numbers_array);
    var_dump($numbers_array);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store your "ticket array" in **a separate table**.
And use regular SQL queries (UPDATE, DELETE) to manipulate it.

A *relational* word in the name of your database is for the reason. And you are abusing this smart software with such a barbaric approach.

Comment: That would be "normalization". But you will be able to use indexes too.

Comment: A "difficult task" is your current screenful of code. While with proper schema it would be one single alone SQL query.